# Specific Timezone when using Google Script API for Spreadsheet

Tags: google-api, timezone, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Script API for filling a spreadsheet from a From Submission. When filling Timestamp it always gets me a different Timezone.

How can I set it to my specific Timezone `EET GMT+2`?

Here an example of my code:

```
var row = [ new Date()];
```

Comment: Did my answer work? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample? In this sample, the converted date can be retrieved by giving the GMT offset. For example, `GMT+2` was given to the following sample.

```
var gap = 2; // GMT+2
var result = new Date(Date.now() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() + gap * 60) * 60 * 1000);
var row = [result];
```

#### Flow :

- `Date.now()` is the unix time. The unit is milliseconds.
- `getTimezoneOffset()` returns the time zone difference, in minutes, from current locale (host system settings) to UTC.
- The unit of `(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() + gap * 60)` is minutes.

  - The unit of milliseconds is obtained by multiplying this by `60 * 1000`.
- By `new Date(Date.now() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() + gap * 60) * 60 * 1000)`, the unix time is converted to the date object.

#### Reference :

- [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

But actually, this didn't work for me. The solution was much easier when I found it out. In the sheet itself from Sheet Preferences ~ Timezone: You can edit your timezone from there.

Comment: @Rafik Semaan Thank you for your additional information. And I am really sorry I couldn't help you.